# Accessing Google Calender API on Android with REST

Tags: android, api, rest, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to access a public google calendar and list the upcoming event inside my Android app.  I am attempting to do this with REST but cannot connect to the website.
This is the url I am attempting to open.
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/frpc9p3dtl73drlglsp7sf3iu4%40group.calendar.google.com/events?key={MY_API_KEY}

Where {MY_API_KEY} is a key that I generated from the google console.  I generated with the SHA1 number listed in eclipse and my application name.
When using the api reference “Try It!” feature it works correctly and returns my calendar events.  When I open the link in Chrome it fails with an limit exceeded error which is what I would expect since I made the key for an Android application, not a browser.
This code opens a connection correctly with google.com and other valid websites.  When stepping through with the debugger the url.openConnection(); appears to fail.

```
byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlSpec);

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

......

I do not believe I want to use OAUTh since I do not want the user to have to sign in with their google account.  I just want to list my own public events.
I am a newer Android developer and have been trying everything I can think of for a couple of days.  I haven’t been able to tease out a message or code why it might be failing, though I strongly suspect it is API related.

Answer (score 0):

In order to access events on a calendar you must have access to that calendar, even if the events themselves are public. If the calendar is public, that's enough. Otherwise you must authenticate (using OAuth) as a user with access to that calendar. You can make the calendar public in the settings page.

Another option would probably be for you to look into service accounts: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount